# Knex get formatted time from a time column and date column

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have a column defined with type time and column defined with type date.

```
knex.schema.createTable('receipt', function(table) {
...
    table.date('t_date');
    table.time('t_time');
...
});
```

It stores data in 24hour format in Database. eg: 22:00:00. Date as '2018-11-30'. But when I run a select query it returns.

```
{
...
    "transactionDate": "2018-11-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "transactionTime": "1970-01-01T22:20:00.000Z",
...
}
```

How to get date from select query with date with format `YYYY-MM-dd` and time as `HH:mm:ssAM/PM`?

Answer (score 5):

Next snippet works like a charm for me:

```
const { setTypeParser, builtins } = require('pg').types;

const typesToReset = [
  builtins.DATE,
  builtins.TIME,
  builtins.TIMETZ,
  builtins.TIMESTAMP,
  builtins.TIMESTAMPTZ,
];

function resetPgDateParsers() {
  for (const pgType of typesToReset) {
    setTypeParser(pgType, val => String(val)); // like noParse() function underhood pg lib
  }
}
```

...and call this function before using your `pg` or library/orm depends on `pg` (knex, objection etc.) requests.

sources: https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/663#issuecomment-351678734 and `console.log(pg.types)`

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the format in which dates etc. column types are returned in javascript is done by database driver and not in `knex`.

For postgresql

[Can we always fetch date column as string (varchar) with knex and postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716120/can-we-always-fetch-date-column-as-string-varchar-with-knex-and-postgres/50717046#50717046)

and for mysql

[Knexjs returning mysql timestamp, datetime columns as Javascript Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103788/knexjs-returning-mysql-timestamp-datetime-columns-as-javascript-date-object/45104227#45104227)

should help.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look now, I'm using mssql driver.

Comment: Nops. In my MySQL table I got YYYY-MM-DD but Knex convert it to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

Comment: Renan, try to read the answer again. It says that the conversion is not made by knex, but by underlying db driver decides how sql types are converted to javascript. For date colums you need to modify a bit the method provided by the linked answer to work for date columns.

Comment: Do y'all know how to achieve this in MSSQL?  It looks like my question is similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63838192/3772763

Comment: Something like `sql.map.register(String, sql.DateTime)` might work. It was mentioned here https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#input-name-type-value but sounds like it might work to input and output.

Answer (score 1):

oracleDb Users have to set this environment variable

```
export ORA_SDTZ='UTC'
```

Further info: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-1008911

Answer (score 0):

### This solution is working fine for me with PostgreSQL 12.

**[Moment](https://momentjs.com) will also resolve the timezone.**

```
const knex = require('knex');
const moment = require('moment');
const { setTypeParser, builtins } = require('pg').types;

setTypeParser(builtins.DATE, val => moment(val).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
setTypeParser(builtins.TIME, val => moment(val).format('HH:mm:ss'));
setTypeParser(builtins.TIMETZ, val => moment(val).format('HH:mm:ss'));
setTypeParser(builtins.TIMESTAMP, val => moment(val).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
setTypeParser(builtins.TIMESTAMPTZ, val => moment(val).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'MHamzaRajput',
        password : 'My@pass@123',
        database : 'my_db',
    }
})
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
var data = {
    "transactionDate": "2018-11-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "transactionTime": "1970-01-01T2:22:00.000Z"
}

var date = data.transactionDate.split("T")[0];
var time = data.transactionTime.split("T")[1].split(".000Z")[0];
let h = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);
let m = time.split(":")[1];
let s = time.split(":")[2];
let suffix = "AM";
if(h >= 12){
 h = h==12 ? 12: h%12;
  suffix = "PM";
}
time =("0" + h).slice(-2)+":"+m+":"+s+"/"+suffix;
console.log(date);
console.log(time);
```

Comment: I could use a moment to format. But I need a knex way. Rather than looping again for each object.

Comment: Actually using moment to format dates to correct format for that view just before showing the value in UI is the correct way to go. When having data as data ISO8061 is a lot more convenient and safe to use.

Comment: This is out of question context.