# KNEX adds extra info to timestamp in server response even though dateStrings: true

Tags: node.js, sql-server, datatables, knex.js

I'm using KNEX, Node/Express, MSSQL (TSQL), and the DataTables/Editor Libraries.

I don't understand what is happening to my timestamps.  I need to return a DATE and a TIME, but extra information is being added to both.

I'm querying a MSSQL View with KNEX in Node:

```
    db.select().table('vueMySuperCoolView')
        .where({ StartDate: date })
        .orderByRaw('StartTime, LogDate')
        .then(data => res.json({ data }))  //responds with named array of objects data:[{}]
        .catch(err => console.log(err));  //more robust error output options exist
```

Here is some of the logic that constructs the view:

```
    select
        cast(t.StartTime as date) as StartDate
        ,cast(t.StartTime as time) as StartTime
```

This produces acceptable output in the MS SQL Management Studio that I can work with:

```
StartDate   StartTime
2020-05-21  09:30:00.0000000
2020-05-21  10:00:00.0000000
2020-05-21  10:30:00.0000000
...
```

**HOWEVER, in the server response, my dates & times look like this:**

```
            "StartDate": "2020-05-22T00:00:00.000Z",
            "StartTime": "1970-01-01T13:30:00.000Z",
```

In a support article, it was recommended that the "dateString" option be set to true, and it is.

```
connection: {
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: 'DB',
    host: 'MSSQL',
    dateStrings: true,
    options: {
           instanceName: 'I'
       }
}
```

**Can you point me in the right direction?**

Comment: Why not [parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/parse) _(you can just use `new Date()`)_ the date and then [format](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format) it to whatever you like it to be?

Comment: I'm working on the assumption that this should be "built in" to the libraries, as there seems to be options for MySQL, Oracle, Postgres.... they're saying it's in the driver (tedious?).  Anyway, one thought I had was to cast the data as varchar, or something.  Also, moment.js and DataTables are kinda taking care of the time conversion stuff.

Comment: JavaScript only has a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) data type which is really a date-with-time. It doesn't have separate Date (date-only) and Time data types. You can supply custom replacers to [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and revivers to [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) if you want different behaviours.

Comment: AFAIK dateStrings: true works only for mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I will happily accept another person's answer if it is better than mine.

The only way I know how to work around this issue is by casting/converting the dates to a `varchar`.

```
    select
        convert(varchar, cast(t.StartTime as date))  as StartDate
        ,convert(varchar, cast(t.StartTime as time), 120) as StartTime  -- grouping value
```

After casting/converting, the date and time is explicitly a `varchar`, without any extra garbage attached to it.  It's available in the frontend for further manipulation (i.e.:  with moment.js).

Another thing that might be important... consider setting `options.useUTC` (do not let KNEX/JS/NODE manipulate the time zone when returning date/time data):

```
        options: {
            instanceName: 'MyInstance',
            // A boolean determining whether or not use UTC time for values without time zone offset (default: true).
            useUTC: false
        }
```

https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/